# gaze trigger event after n seconds - Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I have a 'pointer enter' event, but i only want the event to trigger if the gaze have been active on the object for n seconds.

```
public void PointerEnter() {
   // change scene if the gaze point have been active for n seconds.
}
```

Anyway to achive this ?

Just having a timeout wont do as it will still execute rather the pointer stay locked on the object or not.

Comment: Taka a look at [Unity ScriptReference: StartCoroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html)

Comment: with just a timeout the event is gonna trigger when you look away. - you must have focus on gameobject for n seconds before that happen,  - not just a delay.

Comment: You can cancel the coroutine on PointerExit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a boolean variable to keep state of when pointer has entered and exits by setting it to true and false. This boolean variable can then be checked in the `Update` function. When it is `true`, start a timer and if it becomes `false` during the timer, reset the timer to `0`. Check when timer is more than the x second then load new scene.

The example below assumes that `PointerEnter` is called when pointer is pointing and `PointerExit` when it's no longer pointing. The functions might be different depending on the VR plugin you're using but the rest of the code is the-same.

```
const float nSecond = 2f;

float timer = 0;
bool entered = false;

public void PointerEnter()
{
    entered = true;
}

public void PointerExit()
{
    entered = false;
}

void Update()
{
    //If pointer is pointing on the object, start the timer
    if (entered)
    {
        //Increment timer
        timer += Time.deltaTime;

        //Load scene if counter has reached the nSecond
        if (timer > nSecond)
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene("SceneName");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //Reset timer when it's no longer pointing
        timer = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use pointer event for this at all, but with a simple raycast instead. The pro of doing it this way is that you can also use it in combination with layermasks, tags or anything else you want to use to identify a group of objects, and you don't need to have a pointerevent run on every object you want your gaze to work with. But instead just need a single script on your VRhead or raycaster.

In my example i'll use a layermask. This would make the gaze work on any object in the same layer like "uiButton"

```
public sceneIndex = 0; //build index of the scene you want to switch to

private Ray ray;
private RaycastHit hit;
[serializefield]
private LayerMask myMask;//serializing it will give a dropdown menu in the editor to select the mask layer form, can also use int to select the layer

private readonly float rayLength = 10;
private readonly float timerMax = 5f; //Higher timerMax is a longer wait, lower timerMax is shorter...
private float timer = 0f;

private void Update()
{
    ray = Camera.main.ViewportPointToRay(Vector3.forward);
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, rayLength, myMask))
    {
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
        if(timer >= timerMax)
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneIndex);//load the scene with the build index of sceneIndex
        }
    }
    else
    {
        timer = 0;
    }
}
```

As long as you look at an object within the raycaster's lenght that is on the same layer as `myMask` `timer` will keep increasing until it is bigger or equal to `timerMax`, when this condition is met it will change the scene.